# Issue with Zxing Embedded Continuous QR Code Scanning

Tags: android, android-camera, zxing, android-camera2, android-camera-intent

I'm currently using Zxing Embedded for QR code scanning in continuous mode. However, I'm encountering an issue where it scans randomly from various patterns, including clothes and other non-QR code elements. Has anyone else experienced this problem, and if so, could you please share any solutions or suggestions to fix this issue?

```
barcodeScannerView = findViewById(R.id.scanner_view);
        Collection<BarcodeFormat> formats = Arrays.asList(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, BarcodeFormat.CODE_39);
        barcodeScannerView.getBarcodeView().setDecoderFactory(new DefaultDecoderFactory(formats));
        barcodeScannerView.initializeFromIntent(getIntent());
        barcodeScannerView.setStatusText("");
        beepManager = new BeepManager(this);
        barcodeScannerView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white));
        barcodeScannerView.decodeContinuous(callback);
        CameraSettings cameraSettings = new CameraSettings();
        cameraSettings.setFocusMode(CameraSettings.FocusMode.AUTO);
        cameraSettings.setAutoTorchEnabled(false);
        if (mSession.getIs_top_camera_enabled().equals("1")) {
            cameraSettings.setRequestedCameraId(1); // or CAMERA_FRONT or specific camera id
        } else {
            cameraSettings.setRequestedCameraId(0); // or CAMERA_BACK or specific camera id
        }
        barcodeScannerView.setCameraSettings(cameraSettings);
```

Thank you in advance for your help!
Gaurav Kapoor

Answer (score 0):

After adding few changes in the following code issue is resolved.

```
    barcodeScannerView = findViewById(R.id.scanner_view);
       // Collection<BarcodeFormat> formats = Arrays.asList(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, BarcodeFormat.CODE_39);
Collection<BarcodeFormat> formats = Arrays.asList(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
        barcodeScannerView.getBarcodeView().setDecoderFactory(new DefaultDecoderFactory(formats));
     //Removed   barcodeScannerView.initializeFromIntent(getIntent());
        barcodeScannerView.setStatusText("");
        beepManager = new BeepManager(this);
        barcodeScannerView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white));
        barcodeScannerView.decodeContinuous(callback);
        CameraSettings cameraSettings = new CameraSettings();
        cameraSettings.setFocusMode(CameraSettings.FocusMode.AUTO);
        cameraSettings.setAutoTorchEnabled(false);
        if (mSession.getIs_top_camera_enabled().equals("1")) {
            cameraSettings.setRequestedCameraId(1); // or CAMERA_FRONT or specific camera id
        } else {
            cameraSettings.setRequestedCameraId(0); // or CAMERA_BACK or specific camera id
        }
        barcodeScannerView.setCameraSettings(cameraSettings);
```